# Printing problems

Tags: windows-7, printer

I'm having problems printing to a workstation running windows 7 over the network that I use to print when that workstation was running windows 2000. After the upgrade, prints but page is cut 1/4 to the left of document.

This an Oki  320 microline printer, the software company no longer in business to get an update.

Any help?

Comment: umm by the software company is out of business you mean your ERP software vendor? Oki still has drivers and supports their dot-matrix printers: http://www.okidata.com/mkt/html/nf/Drivers.html

Comment: More information is needed: Is every application you print from doing this or just a single application?  Have you gone into the printer properties from Devices and Printers and see if a setting might need to be changed?  Is there a margin setting on the printer itself that might need to be changed?

Comment: A dot matrix printer? This is 2011! Save yourself the aggro and get a new printer.

Comment: @Mick Dot matrix printers are still in wide use, especially in warehouses, manufacturing and other locations where speed and volume are the priority, or where printing to multilayer carbon-copy paper is still very common.  Just because they're no longer used in homes or corporate locations doesn't mean there isn't still a big demand for them.  Of course, I don't think I've used one in close to 15 years myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "prints but page is cut 1/4 to the left of document."?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Windows 7 Compatibility Center, this should still work for this OS http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Oki%20Microline%20320%20Turbo%20Printer&v=Oki&uid=62412901&l=en-US&pf=0&pi=5&s=Oki%20320%20microline%20printer&os=64-bit

I would suggest running the printer troubleshooter from the Windows site: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-printer-problems

Answer (score 0):

I've read this question a few times and it finally made sense to me! He's using the windows 7 pc as bridge between the ERP server and printer (keep in mind the oki 320's don't have network ports). So what is probably happening is the problems are arising from the sending of the job to the windows 7 machine from the erp server/software. I thought something sounded a little odd when he mentioned printing to the work station not from it, I figured it was a typo. Below is a picture of the oki 320 I have laying around, what you need is that little blue thing that plugs into the second port (it looks like a parallel port when the adapter is unplugged). I checked the one I have hooked up and can't find any model or manufacturer information on it, I know the printer is fairly new but the adapter is pretty old (mid 90's). [Here](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=print+server&cid=10465654872739896541&ei=W1WCTZi_MJyYwgXmrOngBg&sa=title&ved=0CAcQ8wIwADgA#p) is one that should work for what you want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the "Okidata ML 320-IBM" driver.

But it works fine now.

Comment: Go figure -- using the Okidata Microline 320 driver for an Okidata Microline 320 makes it work.. :/